# solaris + fit egrep for solaris

Tags: linux, grep, solaris

On Linux machines I use this syntax, in order to match all VALID ip's.

My question: what needs to change for egrep command in order to run the egrep on Solaris?

According to egrep manual page "-o" isn't a legal option.

What is the alternative for Solaris?

```
     regex="(1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.(1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.(1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.(1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])"

     egrep  -o  `echo $regex` file
```

example of file

```
32)5.500.5.5*kjcdr
##@$1.1.1.1+++jmjh
1.1.1.1333
33331.1.1.1
@5.5.5.??????
~3de.ede5.5.5.5
1.1.1.13444r54
192.9.30.174
&&^#%5.5.5.5
:5.5.5.5@%%^^&*
:5.5.5.5:
**22.22.22.22
172.78.0.1()*5.4.3.277
```

Comment: I believe you missed a $ sign: `echo $regex`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my Solaris systems, even the xpg4 version of `grep` does not include the `-o` option.

But if you have the SUNWggrp package installed, you'll find GNU egrep available as `/usr/sfw/bin/gegrep`.